# How can you edit the Accent Menu?

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization

The English language doesn't really include any accented words but other languages do.
Yet I like to write using accents and diacritics, as needed in each language (Romanian, French, German, etc.).

Unfortunately Mac OS X has never really made it easy to accent a letter before. Lion has simplified it, now accenting a letter is easy thanks to the **Accent Menu** -- [example](http://www.scottexplains.com/2011/07/typing-accented-characters-in-os-x-lion.html):

[image: Accent Menu]

Still, if you take Romanian as an example, most of the specific diacritics are not reachable via the Accent Menu:

- <kbd>a</kbd> » ă
- <kbd>s</kbd> » ș
- <kbd>t</kbd> » ț

Is there a way to edit the Accent Menu to add the accents that are used for a specific language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This menu does include the Romanian diacritics when you're using the Romanian input source. I've provided a tutorial on quickly changing the input sources in:

[How can you customize the keyboard layout / shortcuts?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40372/how-can-you-customize-the-keyboard-layout-shortcuts)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this asked quite a few times since Lion was released last year, but as far as I know, nobody has found how to customize it yet.

I don't think it is that difficult to make accented characters, however, with either the US or US Extended layouts.  A chart is at

http://homepage.mac.com/thgewecke/diacritics.html

Comment: This link would benefit from an update :-)

Comment: @nohillside I suspect that this answer may have referred to [dead keys](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh27474/mac), but that solution is again limited to major Western European languages. It won't allow typing letters such as șțăőűð, some of which were requested in the question, and all of which I need to type.